# What's the point of remote/cloud memcached service?

Tags: caching, heroku, redis, memcached

As far as I understand, memcached is mainly used to cache key value objects in local memory to speed up access.

But on platform like heroku, to use memcached you have to choose add-on like Memcachier, which is cloud based. I don't understand why is that useful? The network latency is orders of magnitude higher than accessing local memory and completely unpredictable.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the applicable use cases, e.g. accessing a remote disk-based RDBMS or performing an expensive computation, the network latency is orders of magnitude lower than the alternative. Furthermore, while it is true that networks are generally unreliable, during normal operation you still get sub-millisecond latency.

That said, usually a local cache beats a remote cache in terms of latency but on the other hand it could prove problematic to scale.

**Edit**: answering the OP's comment.
You can essentially think of a disk-based DB as a memory cache over the data in disk - but the DB server's RAM is limited (like any other server). An external cache is therefore used to offload some of that stress, reduce the contention on the DB server resources and free it for other tasks.

As for latency, yes - I was referring to AWS' network. While I'm less familiar with Memcachier's offer, we (Redis Labs) make sure that our Memcached Cloud and Redis Cloud instances are co-located in the same data region as Heroku's dynos are to ensure minimal possible latency. In addition, we also have an Availability Zone Mapping utility that makes it possible to have the application and cache instances reside within the same zone for the same purpose.

Comment: How about DB's own cache? I think most DB has its own cache, if it's turned on, would memcached still make sense? Also the sub ms latency is only achievable if the memcached server is in the same region?